# Invite a friend to app using Facebook Graph API

Tags: android, ios, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to invite a friend to use my Facebook app, using the "apprequest" method, as described in this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/.

However, only friends that are already using the app can see the request!

How can I send an invitation to someone who isn't already using the app?

Thanks.

Comment: [Look at this tutorial.][http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/games/requests/]

Answer (score 3):

It turns out I was using the right code all along, but my app was in sandbox mode!

Turning off sandbox mode fixed my issue! :)